# How to convert a 1-0 excel csv file into R as binary matrix?

Tags: r, csv, binary

I have a 1-0 matrix data from excel csv file for market basket analysis to apply association rule. However, program cannot find any rule. Probably, it reads the 0 and 1s as string. When I convert to them numeric, the program gives error and cannot generate any rules again.

How can I convert it to binary variables in order to use in association rule finding?

```
  > y <- read.transactions("C:/Users/toshıba pc/Desktop/2009.csv")
    Warning message:
    In asMethod(object) : removing duplicated items in transactions
    > rules <- apriori(y, parameter=list(supp=0.1, conf=0.8))
    Apriori

    Parameter specification:
     confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen target   ext
            0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5     0.1      1     10  rules FALSE

    Algorithmic control:
     filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
        0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

    Absolute minimum support count: 52 

    set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
    set transactions ...[553 item(s), 521 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
    sorting and recoding items ... [0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
    creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
    checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
    writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
    creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].

> rules <- apriori(y, parameter=list(supp=0.01, conf=0.8))
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen target   ext
        0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5    0.01      1     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 5 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[553 item(s), 521 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
> enter image description here
```

Comment: Can you provide more information to your `y` variable. For example `str(y)`.

Comment: I edited the codes. By the way; in other code; I tried to make "y" matrix by using "as.matrix(y)" and " as.numeric(y)". When these two are applied; the rules algorithm did not even work. @PetrMatousu
And If you look the code that I have edited; when I changed the support value; the minimum support count decrases however it still cannot find any rules.

Comment: Maybe snippet of your `csv` file may help as well.

Comment: just FYI your code as.matrix(matrix) is in fact producing atomic vector, therefore your code stops working, as it expects matrix

Answer (score 0):

As a general advice, I suggest to specify more arguments in `read.transactions` to reflect specifics of given `csv` file like separator, cols, etc. Some `csv` file treatment may be needed to reflect `read.transactions` expectations.

```
> args(read.transactions)
function (file, format = c("basket", "single"), sep = "", cols = NULL, 
    rm.duplicates = FALSE, quote = "\"'", skip = 0, encoding = "unknown") 
NULL
```

Function documentation:

```
> ?read.transactions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mba_mat = read_xls(address, sheet = "Sheet1") # rows are transactions, columns are items
mba_trans = as(as.matrix(mba_mat), "transactions") # converting to transactions
class(mba_trans)   #class is transactions
```